# Import users from table to asp.net identity AspNetUsers table?

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am not using `asp.net membership`.  I currently just have a table with a `userId, firstName, and lastName` and I was curious on how I can import these users into an `AspNetUsers table from asp.net identity`?

I was going to set the password to something like `test` for now.

Answer (score 2):

you can add these fields by defining your own User class which inherits from IdentityUser and add these fields on your custom User class